# What is the difference between two sentences.?

Tags: meaning

1-)Of course it is not **long before** the strawberries are all gone.
2-)Of course it is not **long** the strawberries are all gone.

> Gretel takes a strawberry from the basket and pops it into her brother’s mouth. He sucks on it. It is the most delicious taste in the world, and it is far too good to resist another one. **Of course it is not long before the strawberries are all gone.**

Comment: The second has an essential word left out!

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0):

My answer is essentially an elaboration of Kate Bunting’s comment.

> Of course it is not long

is a perfectly idiomatic clause, but it is extremely vague. What does “it” refer to?

> The strawberries are gone

is also a perfectly idiomatic clause, but it indicates nothing about sequence and has nothing to do with duration.

To express your thought of

> Of course, the strawberries were gone before long

in a complex sentence, you need to use “before” as a conjunction linking the two thoughts

> Of course, it was not long before the strawberries were all gone.